# Get woocommerce order details from database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any one know how to get Woocommerce order item details from database. I need like select order id, order date cuopen code like data.. I am trying all this data to get laravel view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is well documented here - https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/ - once you have the order ID, you can easily get all the info you need. Cheers.

Comment: I see now similar question check this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details

Comment: I need access all this from larave? I need know about stored location database columns